# How can i set data from server side at dhtmlx gantt lightbox template tag

Tags: lightbox, controltemplate, dhtmlx

```
gantt.attachEvent("onBeforeLightbox", function(id) {
    var task = gantt.getTask(id);
    task.my_template = "<span id='title1'>Holders: </span>"+ task.users
    +"<span id='title2'>Progress: </span>"+ task.progress*100 +" %";
    return true;
});
```

it is code for set data.
But
 I want to set data from server side.
example:

```
$.getJSON('/production_planning/order_assignment/line_status/?line_id='+line_id, function(data) {
  $('#my_template').html(data)
 });
```

It is Possible using template control?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [gantt.getLightboxSection](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_getlightboxsection.html) method to access the template control from the callback

```
$.getJSON('/production_planning/order_assignment/line_status/?line_id='+line_id, function(data) {
  gantt.getLightboxSection("my_template").setValue(data);
});
```

Comment: It seems like a bug. Please create topic regarding the issue at dev forum http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewforum.php?f=15 (registration needed)